# Loop through .xml files stored in a folder and format it using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have around 100 excel files saved as .xml in my folder and I have written a VBA code which formats the layout settings of each worksheet of all the workbooks(files) in my folder. But the problem is the code does not work on the last worksheet of all the workbooks, it works perfectly fine for the rest i.e. till the last worksheet of each workbook.
Here is the code:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xml"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    ' added this line, loop through all worksheets in current wb
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets

        'Change the layout
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
        With sht.PageSetup
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
            .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        End With
        Application.PrintCommunication = True
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
        Application.PrintCommunication = False
        With sht.PageSetup
            .LeftHeader = ""
            .CenterHeader = ""
            .RightHeader = ""
            .LeftFooter = ""
            .CenterFooter = ""
            .RightFooter = ""
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .PrintHeadings = False
            .PrintGridlines = False
            .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
            .PrintQuality = 600
            .CenterHorizontally = False
            .CenterVertically = False
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Draft = False
            .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
            .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
            .Order = xlDownThenOver
            .BlackAndWhite = False
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
            .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
            .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
            .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
            .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
            .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
            .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
            .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        End With
    Next sht

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please let me know where I went wrong.
Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, goes wrong? Is there an error (if so, on what line)? Is it just not behaving as expected?

Comment: @Mikegrann No there is no error. It does not format the last sheet of each workbook. Thus not completely behaving the way I want it to

Comment: Add line `sht.Activate` right after loop starts at `For Each sht In wb.Worksheets`

Comment: @dbmitch you mean this way? It didn't work on the last tab                                                                    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
    sht.Activate

Comment: What happens when you change `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""` to `Sht.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""`

Comment: @SiddharthRout It still didn't work on the last tab

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in th eline `For Each sht In wb.Worksheets` and check how many worksheets are there using `?Debug.print wb.worksheets.count` in immediate window?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am just a beginner trying my hand at VBA scripting, I don't really understand you here, sorry

Comment: @SiddharthRout Idid as you said, the count is 3, the count is correct but why is it not formatting the 3rd tab?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure. You code looks ok to me. Any chance of me see a sample xml file? If yes, then please upload it to a free file sharing site and share the link here? It is 1 AM here and I am about to hit the sack. Will look at it when I get up?

Comment: @SiddharthRout you can check it on an excel file too myExtension = "*.xlsx"
just make this change

Comment: ok will do it when i get up in the morning :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you so much.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I am still waiting for your answer, really stuck with this :/

Comment: Sorry. I thought I posted an answer. Posting it. One moment

Comment: It worked, thanks! only thing is it works pretty slow now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the lines which say

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```